# SQL backup and rollback a transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, backup

I want to backup my database, but some of the tables are very large and aren't needed for the purposes of the backup. I only need the back up to copy the database onto a local database, and the data in those tables is not necessary.

So I tried to create a transaction where it would delete the data in those tables, make the backup (which will be much smaller with those tables emptied), and then rollback the transaction.

However, I get the error:

> Cannot perform a backup or restore operation within a transaction.

Is there another way I could achieve this?

```
begin transaction t1


declare @date datetime 
set @date = '2015-2-3'

declare @database varchar 
set @database = 'MyDataBase'

declare @backupname varchar
set @backupname = @database + convert(varchar, @date )

delete from VeryBigTable where EffectiveDate < @date

backup database @database
 with name = @backupname


rollback transaction t1
```

Comment: The error message says it all....you can't do this. It doesn't make sense logically what you are doing here. A backup creates a system file which is outside the transaction. Should the rollback delete the file you created or leave it? Since this is very ambiguous you simply can't do it. Restore your database to a copy and delete the data you don't want.

Comment: I understand that I can't do it within a transaction, I was just wondering if there is any other way I could get the same effect. Cutting down on the size of the database *before* backing up would save me a lot of time in backing up, transfering the backup file, and restoring.

Comment: No you can't do that without removing the data but it sounds like you don't want to delete the rows you just want to exclude some tables prior to backup. You could create a staging database and copy in only the tables you want to keep and use that as your backup.

Comment: Okay, I thought that might be the case, but I thought I'd check to see if anyone had any ideas. thanks!